# How to Deploy Local Package to Shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to deploy an app to Shiny.io with a new package via `rsconnect::deployApp()` that I have developed locally and not hosted on CRAN. My question is similar to this [one](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-use-local-packages-in-shinyapps-io/23709/8) but I cannot solve using the same recommendation.

My package is installed on a private github repository and my shinyapps.io account settings have access to this private repo. My app depends on packages both on CRAN and now also this new one I have developed.

Could use a bit of direction on how to solve this.

Thanks

```
Uploading bundle for application: 5447651...Warning: 
* May be unable to deploy package dependency 'Mycpp'; could not determine a repository URL for the source 'CRAN'.

* Unable to determine the source location for some packages. Packages should be installed from a package repository like CRAN
  or a version control system. Check that options('repos') refers to a package repository containing the needed package
  versions.
DONE
Deploying bundle: 6849209 for application: 5447651 ...
Waiting for task: 1273530594
  building: Processing bundle: 6849209
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Building image: 8100493
  building: Fetching packages
  building: Building package: Mycpp
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1273530595 failed: Error building image: Error fetching Mycpp (1.0) source. <CRANPackageSource repo='http://cran.rstudio.org'> unable to satisfy package: Mycpp (1.0)
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Package 'Mycpp 1.0' was installed from sources; Packrat will assume this package is available from a CRAN-like repository during future restores
```

Comment: on the machine being used for deployment, how has the package Mycpp been built ? locally from source; or via install from the private github ? I think it must be the latter for the deployment to work correctly. Perhaps uninstall your package on the local / deploying machine; and install from github to be sure of this; and then try the deployment again ?

Comment: Thanks, Nir. Having a small bit of trouble doing this as it's different than what I normally do. Just moved my .tar file to a public repo and am trying this. Suppose my public repo is 'https://github.com/name/data" and the file in this directory is Mycpp_1.0.tar.gz, what is the canonical way to install from that location?

Comment: `rsconnect::deployApp` is generally smart enough to know how to install github packages when the package is clearly (in the local environment) installed from that location. That is, if you `devtools::load_all` the package from a local directory, then `rsconnect` will _assume_ that the package will somehow be magically available on the remote side (often not the case). However, if you first `remotes::install_github("name/data")` the package, then `rsconnect::deployApp` should recognize this and use that on the remote end (at least, that is how I think it should work).